# Last "if" in "If else" function not working // Error "unreachable code detected ts(7027)"

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

```js
const playerText = document.querySelector("#playerText");
const computerText = document.querySelector("#computerText");
const resultText = document.querySelector("#resultText");
const choiceBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".choiceBtn");


let player;
let computer;

let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let ifresult = "";

choiceBtns.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", () => {

    player = button.textContent;
    computerSelection();
    playerText.textContent = "Player: " + player;
    computerText.textContent = "Computer: " + computer;
    resultText.textContent = "Result: " + result();
}));

function computerSelection(){

    const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    switch(randNum){
      case 1:
        computer = "rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        computer = "paper";
        break;
      case 3:
        computer = "scissors";
        break;
    }
}
function result() {
    if ((player === "paper" && computer === "rock") || 
        (player === "scissors" && computer === "paper") || 
        (player === "rock" && computer === "scissors")) {
       
        playerScore += 1;
        return ("You win! ");
    }
    
    if (playerScore == 2) {
        return ("Winner winner chicken dinner! You won the game!");
    }
    
    else if (player == computer) {
        return ("Draw!");
    } 
    
    else {
        computerScore += 1;
        display ("you lose");
    
    if (computerScore == 5) {
        return ("You lost the game. ");
        }
    }   
    }
```

Everything in this function works except this final if statement in the else bracket.

```
if (computerScore == 5) {
    return ("You lost the game. ");
```

I am getting the error,

> "unreachable code detected ts(7027)".

If I delete the "return ("You lose!");" how would i display i lost the game? The second return "return ("You lost the game.");" returns that statement if i lose 5 times. Thanks for the help

Comment: 1) Your example has too many closing brackets so won't even compile, is that a typo? 2) I edited your layout because sensible indentation and line spacing _really_ helps when trying to debug and make sense of control blocks like `if` and `else` and loops etc. 3) The `if` in question cannot ever be executed because of the `return ("You lose!");` just above it, which causes the code to exit the function. I assume you left this in by accident, since you have another "you lose" type of message just below it

Comment: It's hard to see what you don't understand about the error message. You are returning just before that statement, which is why it can never be reached.

Comment: If I delete the "return ("You lose!");" how would i display i lost the game? The second return "return ("You lost the game.");" returns that statement if i lose 5 times.

Comment: You could just _display_ "you lose" without actually needing to exit the entire game. Showing a message doesn't need to result in termination of the program.

Comment: P.S. Is this code you've shown us inside a function, or just the main block of your program? It's unclear. A bit of context might help with suggesting a better approach.

Comment: Hi sorry about that i can put my entire code for context.

Comment: Ok thanks. In that case I think you can just put `return("You Lose");` in an else,  e.g. `if (computerScore == 5) {
        return ("You lost the game. ");
        } else { return("You lose"); }` so it gets returned in cases where the computer score is not 5. I think that probably makes the most logical sense. Beware that of course the game will not actually be stopped when the computer gets to 5, it simply displays a slightly different message. Maybe you were plannig to tackle that later?

Answer (score 2):

In your final `else` statement, you're returning a value before the `if` condition is run.

```
  return ("You lose!");

  if (computerScore == 5) { // this code is unreachable
```

You need to remove this return.

```
} else {
  computerScore += 1;

  if (computerScore == 5) {
    return ("You lost the game.");
  }
}
```

Comment: If I delete the "return ("You lose!");" how would i display i lost the game? The second return "return ("You lost the game.");" returns that statement if i lose 5 times. Thanks for the help

Comment: You could move the return after the if statement or move `if (computerScore == 5)` into its own `else if` with the final `else` being `return ("You lose!");`

Comment: Im unsure of what you mean by this. put the return after the ifelse statement is closed?

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid such mistakes by adding a good extension into your VS Code. Image below demonstrates how my plugin detected the mistake. I am using Tabnine.
   [image]

2. Be careful when returning values to close the if statement and then start new one.
3. There are some logic issues that makes this function a bit hard to read and unscalable.
4. Using your params I have cleaned and fixed it. I think your level of programming will fit into this solution. Since you are learning then it's OK to write longer code and with time your skill will come.
5. You can test this game, change the function values under the script.

```js
// DEFINE VARIABLES
let player = undefined
let computer = undefined
let playerScore = 0
let computerScore = 0
let returnText = undefined

const theGame = (player, computer) => {
    // PLAYER HAS PAPER
if (player === 'paper' && computer === 'rock') {
    playerScore++
    returnText = 'You win!'
    checkScore(playerScore, computerScore)
    return returnText

} else if (player === 'paper' && computer === 'paper') {
    returnText = 'Draw!'
    return returnText

} else if (player === 'paper' && computer === 'scissors') {
    computerScore++
    returnText = 'You lose!'
    checkScore(playerScore, computerScore)
    return returnText
}
// PLAYER HAS ROCK
if (player === 'rock' && computer === 'rock') {
    returnText = 'Draw!'
    return returnText

} else if (player === 'rock' && computer === 'paper') {
    computerScore++
    returnText = 'You lose!'
    checkScore(playerScore, computerScore)
    return returnText

} else if (player === 'rock' && computer === 'scissors') {
    playerScore++
    returnText = 'You win!'
    checkScore(playerScore, computerScore)
    return returnText
}
// PLAYER HAS SCISSORS 
if (player === 'scissors' && computer === 'rock') {
    computerScore++
    returnText = 'You lose!'
    checkScore(playerScore, computerScore)
    return returnText

} else if (player === 'scissors' && computer === 'paper') {
    playerScore++
    returnText = 'You win!'
    checkScore(playerScore, computerScore)
    return returnText

} else if (player === 'scissors' && computer === 'scissors') {
    returnText = 'Draw!'
    return returnText
}
}

// CHECK SCRORE FUNCTION
const checkScore = (playerScore, computerScore) => {
    let winningScore = 3
    let result = undefined
    if (playerScore === winningScore) {
        result = 'Winner winner chicken dinner! You won the game!'
    } else if (computerScore === winningScore) {
        result = 'Winner winner chicken dinner! You won the game!'
    } else {
        // For testing
        console.log('Player score: ', playerScore, 'Computer score: ', computerScore)
        return playerScore, computerScore
    }
    // For testing
    console.log(result)
    return result
}

// TESTING
theGame('paper', 'rock')
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you put after a return statement will not be executed.

If the last else statement is reached, the function will return “You lose!” and its execution will stop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is technically correct, you should take a look at amcquaid's answer. It provides meaningful code to **show** why.

Comment: If I delete the "return ("You lose!");" how would i display i lost the game? The second return "return ("You lost the game.");" returns that statement if i lose 5 times.